# How to get the benefits of both dynamic imports and SplitChunksPlugin with Webpack 4?

Tags: webpack, webpack-4, dynamic-import

Is it possible to get the benefits of both dynamic imports and split chunks ([SplitChunksPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/))?

#### dynamic imports

When I use dynamic imports I get one chunk per library that has been dynamically imported. However, anything that is statically imported gets added to the same (big) bundle. pseudocode:

```
// my-module.js
const foolib = await import('foolib');
export default foolib('some-arg');
```

results in:

- `foolib.bundle.js` contains only `foolib`, great
- `my-module.bundle.js` contains `my-module` **and** every static import, not great

#### SplitChunksPlugin

Does the other half of what I want. pseudocode:

```
// my-module.js
import foolib from 'foolib';
export default foolib('some-arg');
```

results in:

- `my-module.bundle.js` contains `my-module` only, great
- `vendors.bundle.js` contains all the node_modules dependencies, great

But, this solution lacks dynamic loading.

#### dynamic imports with custom chunks

The idea is that this config would get me all the things.

- `foolib.bundle.js` contains only `foolib` because it was dynamically imported
- `my-module.bundle.js` contains `my-module` only
- `vendors.bundle.js` contains all the node_modules dependencies

---

The results I've gotten so far are that dynamic imports are not considered when you add the `optimization` key (add the splitChunks) to the `webpack.config.js`.

In what direction should I further investigate? My hunch is that maybe I can find a way to better tune the way dynamic imports is generating chunks, but maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: dynamic imports will always get one chunk per import. What else you can do is target all chunks when doing the cache groups, all or async

Comment: I'm also interested in a solution. Did you have find any?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Paragons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-paragons). It uses both dynamic imports and split chunks. The BundleAnalyzerPlugin plugin is setup for the production mode. After you generate my-app, you can do `npm run build` and the client report will be emitted in the dist directory. Here is a sample screenshot:

[image]

You can also check out the [Webpack config](https://github.com/joseki-tech/generator-paragons/blob/master/generators/app/templates/paragons-template/webpack.config.js).